# Why are lamps and mesh lights not illuminating anything?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, light

There are several techniques to do a 3 point lighting system.

How do you properly light a scene while using mesh planes as emission light sources?

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T70ia5GMmzo&index=16&list=PLzmyR17f55-LVbgnzhS4Xl9zJ3dSCdYW3), however despite setting up planes to act a lighting sources, the scene is still very dark.

[image]
[image]

Actual Blender file here: 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/460997/clock%20copy.blend

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your file, [*Clamp direct*  and *Clamp indirect*](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/settings/integrator.html#tricks) have both been set to `.03` in *Render settings > Sampling*.

This is forcing all the samples to return a value less than or equal to .03, which results in the apparent lack of light.

Set them both to zero to disable clamping:

[image]

Then it should work as expected:

[image]