# Why aren't lights affecting my scene?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

Each time I add a new light into my blender scene it doesn't show up or have any effect on the environment.  I tried increasing the strength and messing with the translate, rotate, and scale of the light as well as trying different kinds of lights.  But no matter what I do it doesn't show up or have any effect on the render.

Comment: Could you please post a .blend? I would use Blend Exchange http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: could you post a screenshot of your viewport with all options visible

Comment: make sure you are adding the lamps to the layer you are rendering.

Comment: Make sure clamp isn't set: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/17748/599

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it was because i was in the local view (<kbd>Numpad /</kbd>), didn't realize it before i figured out there were no layer selection.

hope this helps someone to not be stupid like me.