# why does world background appear very dark when rendered?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I was getting a perfectly blue and white cloudy colourful background but somehow it seems all darkened, I must've change some settings unintentionally, but I can't figure our how to put it back normal. can you please help me?
here is a screen shot from my render

dark background

[image]

normal background which I want it back :)
[image]

blender [file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38453)
I'm using cycles with pro skies add-on

Comment: Could you post your World Shader node setup? It may be something related with the Strenght, or the Environment map's colors, or a wrong socket connection.

Comment: Are your clamp settings set to 0 in *Render settings > Sampling*?

Comment: ok i 've added the blend file

Comment: @gandalf3 yes, clamp direct was 0.03, i put it back to 0. but the reason I was using it was to avoid fire flies I wasn't aware of it'd be causing background go darker. is there anyway to avoid it get darker while clamp values non-zero?

Comment: @ideorium It causes the render to go darker because it limits the maximum value a sample can return. If you set to to something greater than 1 (e.g. 1 or 2, depending on how much you can afford to let highlights to be clamped), it should still mitigate fireflies while still keeping the render normal looking.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might have set the [clamp settings set too low](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/17748/599).
Try increasing them until you find a good balance between highlights and fireflies (I typically use something like 2, but you might be able to get away with 1).

You can probably leave *Clamp Direct* at 0, since direct bounces typically don't result in fireflies.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question searching for why my sky nodes were not working.  With help from IRC we figured out the Use Environment checkbox in my render layers was unchecked:

[image: Use Environment is unchecked]

So my problem wasn't a dark texture, it was just blackness.